# SUSE 12 zypper can't install unsigned package non interactively

Tags: bash, zypper

I have a problem with SUSE 12 `zypper`.

I need to install an unsigned package with zypper in non-interactive mode from script. Unfortunately, `zypper` version is 1.13 and there is no option for flag `--allow-unsigned-rpm`. So I've been trying to "pipe" output of the `printf` command into `zypper`, but having no luck so far.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
printf "y\ni\n" | sudo zypper install UNSIGNED_RPM_PATH_HERE
```

What am I doing wrong? This pipe works for every other script I tried to write myself.

Answer (score 1):

Found "solution" to my problem.
I edit `/etc/zypp/zypp.conf` file while my script executes. You can add `pkg_gpgcheck = off` to turn off signature checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--no-gpg-checks` flag

```
sudo zypper --no-gpg-checks install UNSIGNED_RPM_PATH_HERE
```